# WSUS Computers exported: Filter that CSV file with Powershell in import

Tags: powershell, csv, import, export

Hello I need to filter a .csv file with powershell.
I exported the information like this:

Get-WsusComputer -ComputerTargetGroups "group" | Export-Csv -Path "C:\export.csv"

but Get-WsusComputer adds more information into that .csv than I need, I only want the "FullDomainName" so I can add those computers to a new AD-Group.
Therefore I need  to filter for only the header "FullDomainName" when importing. how do i do that?

I tried this:

Import-Csv "C:\export.csv" -Delimiter "," | select "FullDomainName"

but when doing that and trying to print out the imported values, the imported values look like this:

@{FullDomainName=blablabla.de}

Im quite new to powershell, but to my understanding that import would not be right this way to after that be used to add those fulldomainnames to a new AD-Group.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `select FullDomainName` creates a new object with 1 property named `FullDomainName`, the value of which is copied from the input. If you want just the _value_ of `FullDomainName` on each input object, do `...| select -expand FullDomainName` or `...| ForEach-Object FullDomainName`

Comment: Thank you. But if i import like this: $computers = Import-Csv "C:\export.csv" -Delimiter "," | ForEach-Object FullDomainName and I want to do the following then: Get-ADComputer $computers   It cant convert from "System.Object[]" to "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADComputer"

Comment: `$computer |Get-ADComputer`

Comment: I don't understand. This is my full code i have for the import and add to ADGroup now: $computers = Import-Csv "C:\export.csv" -Delimiter "," | ForEach-Object FullDomainName            ForEach ($computer in $computers) { $obj = Get-ADComputer $computers Add-ADGroupMember -ID mygroup -Members $obj}           And it says cant convert from sytem.object to microsoft.activedirectory.... AND Argument for paramter "Member" can not be validated.

Comment: You're doing `Get-ADComputer $computers` instead of `Get-ADComputer $computer`

Comment: Oh god yea, thank you, my bad. Problem now is it says it cant find the computer names in my OU.. eventhough if i manually search them in AD they are there. Still same error message "Argument for paramter "Member" cant be validated. its null or empty". But I assume that is because it says that it cant find the computer in the OU right? Which doesnt makes sense to me, as they are literally in the exact OU powershell says they are not.

Comment: Please see the answer I've posted below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `FullDomainName` contains the FQDN of the target machines (eg. `computer01.child.domain.tld`), loop over the names and split them into a name and domain, then query AD like this:

```
$computerFQDNs = Import-Csv "C:\export.csv" -Delimiter "," |ForEach-Object {
    $name,$domain = $_.FullDomainName -split '\.',2
    $computerAccount = Get-ADComputer -Identity $name -Server $domain -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if($computerAccount){
        # Computer account found, add to group
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity myGroup -Member $computerAccount
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Unable to find computer account '$name' in domain '$domain'"
    }
}
```

The `-split '\.',2` operation will take the input string and split it at the first `.` (ie. `computer.domain.tld` -> `computer` and `domain.tld`)